# Are "combo" updates something we will see in Windows Phone / Mobile future?

Tags: update

I just got a new Windows Phone today. In the first 2 hours, while I was setting up all my Apps, data and preferences the phone found *several* different system updates.

Each time I had to reload the phone, wait for the update to be installed and than, in 15 minutes or less, another update was ready to be installed. Even worse, I had to reload the phone three more times after it had just completed a reload because of Glance, Device Hub and motion data preferences.

I understand this is a one-time only event, since you buy it only once, but it was quite bothering after the second or third update: honestly I lost count, but for sure I did installed **at least four** different release of Windows Phone (and rebooted the phone probably ten times in total).

Comment: Voting to close as we cannot possible objectively answer this question at this point

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any official statement by Microsoft regarding this, bit I assume this will get better with Windows 10 as Mobile will likely benefit from the regular Windows Update system.

It might be an indication that you do not need to install all preview versions of Windows 10 Mobile in order to get to the latest build.

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned [earlier](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12704/18061), in Windows 10 mobile some updates are cumulative(not all). This will allow you to directly install the latest update from Microsoft.

As for your other problems, the device hub has been replaced by a [Gadgets](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/gadgets/9wzdncrfj3df) app(Ref : [WMPoweruser](http://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-replaces-device-hub-app-with-gadgets-app-in-windows-10/)). It is now updated as a regular app without the need for restarting the phone.

Also many core apps such as [Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/microsoft-phone/9wzdncrdtbwp), [Messaging+Skype](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/messaging-skype/9wzdncrfjbq6), Office are now updated via store in Windows 10 mobile. This means that you will not be getting full fledged system updates to update core apps.

I believe that these factors combined may reduce the number of restarts required on a new mobile.